# Python: Not uploading the correct data in firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So a little background information: I am getting some data from websites by scraping the data.

I have two arrays declared, one has all of the team names (16 in total) the other array is the times (they have 8 total items).

I want to put all this information into a dictionary before uploading it into Firebase so basically I need to sort the arrays first. The way it is set up the array that has an even value is the first team the odd value is the opponent.

So that means if I am making a dictionary I can to something like:

```
{"teamone": teamNames[evenValue], "teamTwo": teamNames[oddValue]}
```

I can also attach the time by adding the times array element to that dictionary so:

```
{"timeGameStarts": times[countOfIteration of whole array]}
```

So for my code I have this:

```
teamObjects = {"TeamOne": "", "TeamTwo": "", "Time": ""}
matchPackage = [teamObjects]
print(len(teamNames))
countTwo = 0
for i in times:
    matchPackage.append(teamObjects)
    matchPackage[countTwo] = teamObjects["Time"] = times[countTwo]
    countTwo += 1

countThree = 0
count = 0
for l in teamNames:
    if count % 2 == 0:
        #even number
        matchPackage[countThree] = teamObjects["TeamOne"] = teamNames[count]
    else:
        matchPackage[countThree] = teamObjects["TeamTwo"] = teamNames[count]
        countThree += 1
    print(count)
    count += 1
```

I don't know anything about the Python syntax so this is all just guess work, but basically this produces an incorrect result until the last element. The last element or element 8 in the array is how every single element should look. what is really weird is there shouldn't be 8 elements in Firebase it should be 0 through 7.

[image: how it looks in the database]

Here is all of the team values:

```
0: "Astralis"
1: "Virtus.pro"
2: "Virtus.pro"
3: "Astralis"
4: "Fnatic"
5: "Team EnVyUs"
6: "Team EnVyUs"
7: "Fnatic"
8: "Counter Logic Gaming"
9: "OpTic Gaming"
10: "OpTic Gaming"
11: "Counter Logic Gaming"
12: "Cloud9"
13: "Immortals"
14: "Immortals"
15: "Cloud9"
```

Comment: The python code you provided runs with an error since teamNames is defined outside of this sample. Additional note: In python you don't need to keep counters youself, you can loop over lists like this: for count, item in enumerate(list_of_things):